# error 400 bad request when sending a request using react (fetching data through react to django rest-framework)

Tags: reactjs, django, post, fetch-api

i'm new here and excuse my unfamiliarity with the proper structure of the post.

so i am trying to send json data to a django server using the following link

```
http://localhost:8000/profiles/
```

and I kept searching for hours and I did eveything possible solving the popular 415 error which was the first error. I tried all options possible based on the internet, articles and answers here and finally the options in create.jsx eliminated the first 405 error related to cors. now i'm getting a bad request whenever I try to send data.
[image: error on django]
this is my react code:

**create.jsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Create = () => {
    const[name, setName] = useState("");
    const[email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const[mobile_number, setMobile] = useState("");
    const[national_id, setID] = useState("");
    const[password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const blog = { name, email, mobile_number,national_id,password };


    const options={
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
      body : JSON.stringify(blog)
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/profiles/', options)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('new radiologist added');
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle the error here
        console.log(e);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="create">
      <h2>Add a New Blog</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>name:</label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          required 
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>email:</label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          required 
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>national id:</label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          required 
          value={national_id}
          onChange={(e) => setID(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label> mobile phone </label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          required 
          value={mobile_number}
          onChange={(e) => setMobile(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label> password </label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          required 
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Create;
```

**the django model:**

```
class Radiologist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="123456")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**the url patterns**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("profiles/", ProfileList.as_view()),
    path("profile/<int:pk>", ProfileDetails.as_view()),
    path("profile/<int:pk>/patients", ProfilePatients.as_view()),

    
    path("patients/", PatientList.as_view()),
    path("patient/<int:pk>", PatientDetails.as_view()),
    path("patient/<int:pk>/scans", PatientScans.as_view()),

    path("scans/", ScanList.as_view()),
    path("scan/<int:pk>", ScanDetails.as_view()),
    
    path("scanNew/", ScanViewSet.as_view()),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I tried all options possible (found in the constant called options) and I expect that the post request is sent to the django server without errors.

Comment: enable CORS from the server side, usually in DJango...

Comment: thank you for your response, I added ```"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware", ``` in ```MIDDLEWARE``` as well as ```corsheaders``` in ```INSTALLED_APPS``` and still nothing happend and I installed the django-cors-headers on the project.

Answer (score 0):

usually django will tell you what is the error based on response, try querying using any rest API client like postman. or check developer tools. if it works on postman but not on the browser you probably have cors error. install cors headers and make sure it is on top of other middlewares.

Comment: I tried that but still has the same issue, it works on postman, and Django does not have any problem in post or get requests but the problem remains in sending the post request from React and I feel really overwhelmed.